# ListView not updating despite ItemsSource boud to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a ListView to display a bunch of custom cells, and I need it to update when I modify its content. I have bound its ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection, and I have a method that updates this collection whenever I need. This method is called when I add an element to a persistent collection stored with the Settings plugin, or when the page appears because I can also modify that persistent collection from another page. However, the ListView won't update unless I switch to another tab of my app before coming back.

Here's my code:

ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ViewCell> Cells { get; set; }
        public PlugManagerViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Mes prises";
            Cells = new ObservableCollection<ViewCell>();
        }

        public void RefreshPlugList()
        {
            Cells.Clear();
            foreach ((string name, string desc, _) in Settings.PlugListContent)
            {
                CustomCell cell = new CustomCell
                {
                    Title = name,
                    Detail = desc
                };
                Cells.Add(cell);
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="plugList" x:FieldModifier="public" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemSelected="OpenPlugDetail" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <models:CustomCell Title="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Detail}"></models:CustomCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

XAML.cs:

```
    PlugManagerViewModel _viewModel;

        public PlugManagerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _viewModel = (PlugManagerViewModel)this.BindingContext;

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            _viewModel.RefreshPlugList();
        }

        public async void AddPlug(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to modify Settings.PlugListContent
            _viewModel.RefreshPlugList();
        }

        public async void OpenPlugDetail(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to change page and reset selected item
        }
```

I have already looked up a bunch of other threads and I can't find a working solution. Is my binding broken or is it something else ?

Comment: Where do you create the view model and where do you set the BindingContext?

Comment: What does “not updating” mean?  Is it not showing new items added to the list, or is it not showing edits to existing items?  Why are you adding new “CustomCell” to the list when it’s d3fined as a ObservableCollection<ViewCell>?

Comment: The binding context is set in the XAML within ContentPage.BindingContext.

By not updating, I mean that new items don't appear. I don't update the content of existing cells. And I use ViewCell because CustomCell implements it and I get acessibility issues with CustomCell (ObservableCollection<CustomCell> is less accessible than property PlugManagerViewModel.Cells)

Comment: Where is the code where you actually add a new item?  If that happens on another page, how is your VM being notified?

Comment: The code to add items to Settings.PlugListContent is in the page code, in the AddPlug method. The _viewModel.RefreshPlugList() method is then called to read the content of Settings.PlugListContent and update the ListView accordingly. What confuses me is that the refresh method works when loading the app or coming back from another page (i.e. when it's called from OnAppearing) but not when it's called from AddPlug... and manually calling OnAppearing from AddPlug does nothing more

Comment: I'd expect this to work.  But I'm still not clear on why you're using `ViewCell` - which is a UI element - as the base class for your model.  That may have nothing to do with it but it's the thing that sticks out to me as being strange.

Comment: I modified it to ObservableCollection<CustomCell> after setting the class modifier to public, and it stills fails all the same.

Comment: **Add to question** the declaration of `CustomCell`. `ItemTemplate` should be a ViewCell (or a subclass of VIewCell), but `ItemsSource Cells` should NOT inherit from ViewCell, nor from any other UI type. Also, make sure each source Cell is using **public properties** - not fields. Must have `get/set`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `OnAppearing()` only be triggered before the Page becoming visible. So this is the reason why the ListView won't update unless you switched to another tab then switched back.

You can stop using the `OnAppearing()` method to load the data to fix this issue. you can load the data by use the `ObservableCollection` and `OnPropertyChanged`.

You can check [Page.OnAppearing Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the **ItemSource** should be (**in your Example**) should be **ViewCell**.

Some other suggestions:

1. Use a CollectionView instead of Listview -> [CollectionView-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/)
2. Use another word instead of the misleading "**ViewCell**"
3. As the User Guangyu mentioned - if u r not overriding the OnApperaing()-Method, don't use it.